# Bash if/then sometimes detects file, sometimes doesn't

Tags: bash, macos

I have this script to detect if a file has been fully written (it exists) to the file system.

```
   if [ -e $BACKUPDIR$thissite.$thisenv.$thiselement.$BACKUPDATE.$DBEXTENSION ] 
   then
       echo "Downloaded backup for "$thissite $thisenv $thiselement
   else
       echo "Download failed for "$thissite $thisenv $thiselement
   fi
```

About half the time it detects the file and the other half it doesn't and gives the failure message, even though the file does exist. At first I thought I just needed to add a "sleep 5" line to give time for the file to be written fully. But no matter how long I wait, it sometimes fails even though the file really does exist.

Is there a more accurate way to detect a file?

Thanks.

Comment: This is the most accurate way. It's a 100% guarantee that this is a bug in your script or in your assumptions about the file, and not a bug in Bash. Maybe you fail to set some of the variables correctly, maybe you're racing to get the BACKUPDATE, maybe you're trying to use globs in it, maybe you have another process moving the file. If you want help tracking it down, add `set -x` output along with how you verify that the file exists outside of your script.

Comment: Thanks! I've been googling for what `set -x` is all about, but I'm not getting a clear answer. Either way, because my requirement changed to needing to run this as a cron, I think I'm going to use `exec &> logfile.txt` so I can `more` it to check its daily status.

Comment: You can put `set -x` as a command in your script to enable debug output from that point. It will be written to stderr.

Comment: Another note: `-e` checks whether the file exists *at all*, not whether it's been fully written out. It'll match on files that've been created but not written to at all.